# dropping duplicates randomly

Tags: python, pandas

In `Pandas` we can drop duplicates by using `dataframe.drop_duplicates()` which keeps the first row of the duplicate data by default. If `keep_last = True`, the last row is kept.
How can we keep any random row and drop the duplicate rows using pandas `drop_duplicate`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe:

```
idx = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(df)))
df.iloc[idx].drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 10):

A Pythonic way to accomplish this:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates()
```

Here, we are taking a sample equal to the full size of the dataframe, without replacement. This effectively shuffles the position of all rows, allowing us to drop duplicates and keeping the first row, previously randomized.

If you need to keep the index in sequential order, you could also reset it:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This works really well too if you want to drop based on a subset of columns in the DataFrame, which can't be achieved in the top answer.